problem to generate child elements of SOAP-ENV:Header in the gsoap
I want to create something like this:
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:saml1="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:wsc="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:chan="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/02/duplex" xmlns:wsa5="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:pt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/pacs" xmlns:ns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/humanface" xmlns:ns2="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/humanbody" xmlns:xmime="http://tempuri.org/xmime.xsd" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" xmlns:wsrfbf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:wstop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1" xmlns:wsrfr="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/r-2" xmlns:tac="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/accesscontrol/wsdl" xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" xmlns:tev="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl" xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" xmlns:timg="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/imaging/wsdl" xmlns:tmd="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceIO/wsdl" xmlns:tptz="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl" xmlns:trp="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/replay/wsdl" xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl" xmlns:tse="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/search/wsdl">
     <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <dom0:SubscriptionId wsa5:IsReferenceParameter="true" xmlns:dom0="http://trololo/111/event">1715065920077</dom0:SubscriptionId>
      <dom1:SubscriptionId wsa5:IsReferenceParameter="true" xmlns:dom0="http://trololo/222/event">1715065920078</dom0:SubscriptionId>
      <wsa5:MessageID>urn:uuid:654721e3-4c2e-45ec-a1f3-f581309c6428</wsa5:MessageID>
      <wsa5:To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://127.0.0.1:8088/mockEventsBinding/1715065920077</wsa5:To>
      <wsa5:Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="true">http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/bw-2/SubscriptionManager/RenewRequest</wsa5:Action>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <wsnt:Renew>
         <wsnt:TerminationTime>PT30S</wsnt:TerminationTime>
      </wsnt:Renew>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

So I need several children (dom0:SubscriptionId, dom1:SubscriptionId) in the header
The gsoap has generated such a structure:
struct SOAP_CMAC SOAP_ENV__Header {
      public:
        /** MustUnderstand */
        struct _wsse__Security *wsse__Security;
        /** XML DOM element node graph */
        struct soap_dom_element *__any;
        /** Optional element 'wsa5:MessageID' of XML schema type 'wsa5:MessageID' */
        char *wsa5__MessageID;
        /** Optional element 'wsa5:RelatesTo' of XML schema type 'wsa5:RelatesTo' */
        struct wsa5__RelatesToType *wsa5__RelatesTo;
        /** Optional element 'wsa5:From' of XML schema type 'wsa5:From' */
        struct wsa5__EndpointReferenceType *wsa5__From;
        /** MustUnderstand */
        struct wsa5__EndpointReferenceType *wsa5__ReplyTo;
        /** MustUnderstand */
        struct wsa5__EndpointReferenceType *wsa5__FaultTo;
        /** MustUnderstand */
        char *wsa5__To;
        /** MustUnderstand */
        char *wsa5__Action;
        /** Optional element 'chan:ChannelInstance' of XML schema type 'chan:ChannelInstanceType' */
        struct chan__ChannelInstanceType *chan__ChannelInstance;
      public:
        /** Return unique type id SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Header */
        long soap_type() const { return SOAP_TYPE_SOAP_ENV__Header; }
        /** Constructor with member initializations */
        SOAP_ENV__Header() : wsse__Security(), __any(), wsa5__MessageID(), wsa5__RelatesTo(), wsa5__From(), wsa5__ReplyTo(), wsa5__FaultTo(), wsa5__To(), wsa5__Action(), chan__ChannelInstance() { }
        /** Friend allocator */
        friend SOAP_FMAC1 SOAP_ENV__Header * SOAP_FMAC2 soap_instantiate_SOAP_ENV__Header(struct soap*, int, const char*, const char*, size_t*);
};

and I need to use struct soap_dom_element *__any; to add my children.
However it's not possible. I can add only single node with children like :
<SOAP-ENV:Header><parent><child1/><child2/></parent></SOAP-ENV:Header>

but unable to add children without parent. (While it is required by onvif protocol)
So I tried to set elts to __any as a result I have only first child serialized. Looks like gsoap bug.
the way to create the structure:
        auto first = soap_elt_new(m_event_proxy.Get(), nullptr, "test1");
        first->next = soap_elt_new(m_event_proxy.Get(), nullptr, "test2");
        first->next->next = soap_elt_new(m_event_proxy.Get(), nullptr, "test3");
        m_event_proxy.Get()->header->__any = first;

where m_event_proxy is SoapInitializer<PullPointSubscriptionBindingProxy> ;

Show us the code you tried to add those <SubscriptionId> elements to the header.

Some instructions for an [mre] might help, too. I have no idea how you generated that code from what inputs.

the only way to add siblings is to fullfill "next" member. Or to create childs of node then do the following: m_event_proxy.Get()->header->__any = parent->elts real minimal reproducible example is not possible here

What does your edit have to do with your question?

Ok, the trick was to create a parent empty node like this and set it's type:
m_parameter = soap_elt_new(m_soap, nullptr, nullptr);
m_parameter->type = SOAP_TYPE__XML;

then we should add our nodes as children:
auto parameter1 = soap_elt_new(m_soap, nullptr, "test1");
soap_add_elt(m_parameter, parameter1);
auto parameter2 = soap_elt_new(m_soap, nullptr, "test2");
soap_add_elt(m_parameter, parameter2);

Bingo
